# SQL Server 2017 trigger - declaring variable

Tags: sql-server, triggers

Today's the first time I have to work on SQL Server, usually I use MySQL.

I did some searching, but, I just don't get it.

Here's the code:

```
CREATE TRIGGER "PREMI_after_insert" 
ON "PREMI" 
AFTER INSERT 
AS
    DECLARE @umur INT

    SELECT 
        @umur = DATEDIFF(YEAR, CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE),
       (CASE 
           WHEN ISNUMERIC(SELECT NoTerdaftar FROM inserted) = 1 
              THEN (SELECT CAST(TglLahir AS DATE) 
                    FROM KARYAWAN 
                    WHERE NoPegawai = (SELECT NoTerdaftar FROM inserted)) 
              ELSE (SELECT CAST(TglLahir AS DATE) 
                    FROM KELUARGA 
                    WHERE NoPeserta = (SELECT NoTerdaftar FROM inserted)) 
       END))

    DECLARE @plafond DECIMAL(20,0) 

    SELECT @plafond = (CASE  
                          WHEN ISNUMERIC(SELECT NoTerdaftar FROM inserted) = 1 
                             THEN (SELECT Plafond 
                                   FROM KARYAWAN 
                                   WHERE NoPegawai = (SELECT NoTerdaftar FROM inserted)) 
                             ELSE (SELECT Plafond 
                                   FROM KELUARGA 
                                   WHERE NoPeserta = (SELECT NoTerdaftar FROM inserted)) 
                       END)

    DECLARE @rat DECIMAL(7,6) 

    SELECT @rat = RE.Rate 
    FROM RATES RE 
    WHERE RE.KodeAsuransi = (SELECT JenisAsuransi FROM ASURANSI 
                             WHERE Id = (SELECT ID_Asuransi FROM inserted)) 
      AND @umur BETWEEN RE.UsiaMin AND RE.UsiaMax

BEGIN

    UPDATE PREMI
    SET JumlahPremi = (@plafond * @rat)
    WHERE Id = (SELECT Id FROM insterted)
END;
```

and this is the error

[image]

Please, don't bully me, that code is what I get after reading tons of other thread....

I just don't understand the structure of trigger in SQL Server.

Some use "GO" word, some don't even use BEGIN and END which is the key in MySQL....

Comment: There's a lot wrong here I'm afraid. Firstly, T-SQL uses brackets (`[]`) for object quoting, not double quotes (`"`), but I'm surprised it got to the `SELECT`. Also, however, the method you have used have a massive flaw: It assumes your `INSERT` will only have 1 row, and only 1 row. This is a really bad assumption to make, as it is very often simply not true. What is the logic you are trying to achieve here? *Also, I'd highly recommend making use of White Space and line breaks, that SQL is very difficult to read.*

Comment: @sriharsha it is far worse than just that line. This whole thing is flawed. Subqueries all over the place are a clear indication that something is not quite right. And inside a trigger like this is very problematic.

Comment: There is no fixing this (in it's current form), so many logical errors in here. All is not lost however, it just needs a redesign. We need to understand what you are trying to accomplish and details of the table structure for all the tables involved. My guess is this could be rewritten as a single set based statement.

Comment: A more readable version: [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=a97822f02386048e91a0ce776423b7e3). The reason for the error is actually very simple. When putting a subquery in a function, the sub query needs to be within parathesis. So, instead of `ISNUMERIC(SELECT NoTerdaftar FROM inserted)` it should be `ISNUMERIC((SELECT NoTerdaftar FROM inserted))`. This is, however, ***far*** from the real problem here. There are some huge issues with this query, that myself and Sean have only touched on. If we can understand what your goal is, we can begin to help you rewrite it.

Comment: Also, a final comment. `ISNUMERIC` is honestly an awful function. For example, try `SELECT CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC('.') = 1 THEN CONVERT(int,'.') END`. `ISNUMERIC` returns 1, but the `CONVERT` fails. A far better option is `TRY_CONVERT` and `TRY_CAST`; which returns `NULL` if the conversion fails.

Comment: Looks like you'll also need parenthesis around `SELECT RE.Rate FROM RATES RE WHERE...`

Comment: I might be going query blind, but don't see that clause anywhere in the trigger @Steve-o169 .

Comment: @Larnu Oops, I might've modified it to what I thought it should be.  Personally, I would write the last parameter assignment as `SET @rat = (SELECT RE.Rate FROM RATES RE WHERE...`

Comment: You'll probably get a "Subquery returned more than 1 result" error then @Steve-o169 ;)